# Getting code into a subversion repository

Tags: svn, unfuddle

I just started with subversion, as I'm working with a partner who is not comfortable using git. I signed up for unfuddle, and have a svn url, however when I try to run the svn import command, I get the error

```
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

I'm also unsure why it ask me for two passwords. I tried using the --username option as well to pass my username on unfuddle, but that didn't solve anything.

The command I ran was svn import /path/to/tree http://svn.url/on/unfuddle

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

First, create the repository in unfuddle. 
Then, browse to the repo and click "show me how to connect". Should be something like:

```
svn checkout https://company.unfuddle.com/svn/repo-name/ local_directory_name
```

Then, on your local machine:

```
cd /path/to
svn checkout https://company.unfuddle.com/svn/repo-name/ tree
cd /path/to/tree
svn ci -m "initial commit of code"
```

Comment: Any idea why svn import isn't the right way to go about this?